# Missing natural names with \autoref in Beamer. A beamer bug?

Tags: beamer, hyperref

Using `hyperref` and `beamer` together, I encounter the following problem. Command `\autoref` which is supposed to add the name of the referenced item, does not work.

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{naturalnames}{hyperref}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[naturalnames]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{naturalnames}
\renewcommand{\sectionname}{Unit}
\begin{document}
  \section{My first section} \label{first}
  \begin{frame}
    See \autoref{second}.
  \end{frame}
  \section{My second section} \label{second}
  \begin{frame}
    See \autoref{first}.
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output

[image]

[image]

Notice that that the name "Unit" does not appear in the generated reference.

Comment: I suspect the 'new' labelling system inside of beamer. It leaves no hook which can `\autoref` jump to. If one introduces a dummy counter `foo` and uses `\refstepcounter` and `\label`, `\autoref`, there is no warning about a missing autoref name for `foo`, which indicates that `autoref` is not in action at all

Comment: `\usepackage{cleveref}\crefname{section}{Unit}{Units}`; then `\cref{first}` will print `Unit 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the `.aux` file generated by your code, we find

```
\newlabel{first}{{1}{1}{My first section}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

Removing the `naturalnames` will not cure the problem.

On the other hand, the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Unit}

\begin{document}

\section{First}\label{first}

\autoref{first}

\end{document}
```

will produce

```
\newlabel{first}{{1}{1}{First}{section.1}{}}
```

in the `.aux` file and then print “Unit 1”.

Using `cleveref` seems much easier:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{section}{Unit}{Units}

\begin{document}

\section{My first section}\label{first}

\begin{frame}

See \cref{first}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's basically the same answer I wanted to add, but you were quicker. Nevertheless, I could backtrace the `Doc-Start` *countername* to `\@currentHref{Doc-Start}` within `hyperref.sty`, but I have no idea where it comes into action.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It basically means that `hyperref` finds nothing better to hook to.

Comment: Well, I wonder, if this can be cured, however, your answer with `cleveref` is perhaps really the shortest and best way

Comment: Do note that the `cleveref` references aren't click-able (i.e.) it is plain text.